# Identifying random effects structure to simulate dataset - lmer

Tags: mixed-model, simulation, nested-data, crossed-random-effects

I am trying to simulate a dataset based on an existing study.

60 participants completed the experiment twice. Each time, they were randomly assigned to either condition A or condition B. The condition assignment was independent of the measurement time, so the same participant might or might not have been assigned to the same condition.

The model specified in the study was:

`dv ~ iv + (1|participant) + (condition|time)`

I understand why participant is a random effect, but I don't understand what `(condition|time)` refers to.

In the study description, the authors stated that they "treated participant and measurement time as random factors" (I understand this part), and that "participants were nested in the condition in each measurement time, and the measurement time was crossed with the condition" (I'm not too sure what this means).

Using my limited understanding of this information to simulate the dataset, I generated:

- random intercepts for each participant, of which there are 60
- random intercepts for each possible time-condition combination, of which there are 4:

  - time1-condition
  - time1-conditionB
  - time2-conditionA
  - time2-conditionB

When doing this, my descriptive statistics do not seem to match those of the original study - am I misunderstanding the random effects structure or did I generate the random intercepts incorrectly?

This is my code:

```
# simulate random effect of participant
participants <- tibble(id = 1:n,
                       T_0i = rnorm(n, 0, tau_0)) #random intercept for participant

# simulate random effect of time|condition
timecondition <- crossing(time = 1:time,
                          condition = sample(rep(c('A','B'), times = 2))) %>%
  mutate(O_0i = rnorm(4, 0, omega_0))
#there are four possible combinations of time|condition: time1-A, time1-B, time2-A, time2-B

simdata <- tibble(id = rep(1:60, each = 2), #60 participants undergo 2 time points each
                  time = rep(1:2, times = 60), 
                  condition = sample(rep(c('A','B'), times = 60))) %>%
  mutate(b0 = if_else(condition=="A", b0, 0) %>% #adding in fixed effects
  inner_join(participants, by = "id") %>% #adding in random effect of participant
  inner_join(timecondition, by = c("time", "condition")) %>% #adding in random effect of time|condition
  mutate(sigma = rnorm(120, 0, sigma)) %>% #adding in error term
  mutate(dv = b0 + T_0i + O_0i + sigma) #simulate dv
```

Edit: I'm thinking, perhaps I misunderstood the code `(condition|time)`. I originally thought that this syntax refers to the crossing of condition and time, but maybe it actually means random slope of time, by condition?

Edit: This is the paper I'm using - Huang, Y., Richter, E., Kleickmann, T., & Richter, D. (2022). Class size affects preservice teachers’ physiological and psychological stress reactions: An experiment in a virtual reality classroom. Computers & Education, 184, 104503. https://doi.org/10.1016/j.compedu.2022.104503

Comment: Take a look at this [Model specification](https://tinyurl.com/2ry6yc8d) section to learn more about the notation used by the `lme4` package. And please include a reference to the study.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this! According to this, I believe that `(condition|time)` refers to the random slope of 'condition' within 'time' with correlated intercept. However, the paper (which I have now linked in my post) seems to report only the intercept, not the values of the slope and correlation - is it possible to simulate these values?

Comment: Thank you for the adding the reference. Now I have questions about the model as well.... They say: "Our study design treated class size (condition) as a fixed factor, with participant and measurement time as random factors." and later on "We constructed and tested two sets of linear mixed-effects random intercept models." So even though the model is reported as `Y ~ fixed effects +  (1 | participant) + (class size | time)`, I'd guess the model is actually `Y ~ fixed effects + (1 | participant) + (1 | time)`. That is, there are two random intercepts, one for participants and one for time.

Comment: But then Table C.1 includes random effects `Participant (Intercept)` and `Time | Class size (Intercept)`? Confusing. At no point does the paper mention random slopes. Have you considered writing an email to the authors?

Comment: Hi dipetkov, thanks again for helping me out on this. I'm thinking of completely omitting the second random effect for my simulation - after all there are only 2 measurement times, and a quick google search tells me that random effects terms should generally have at least five levels. What are your opinions on this approach?

Comment: You are right: Two measurement times (two measurement phases?) are too few to justify representing `time` as a random effect. And logically, there is nothing random about those measurement times, right? One rule of thumb is that a random-effect categorical variable has at least 5 categories. [Should I treat factor xxx as fixed or random?](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#should-i-treat-factor-xxx-as-fixed-or-random)